# Using Darboux theorem for $f'$ check whether the given function $f(x)=x-\left[x\right], x\in[0,2]$ is a derivative of a function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> **Using Darboux theorem for $f'$ check whether the given function $f(x)=x-\left[x\right], x\in[0,2]$ is a derivative of a function.**

Please help me to solve the problem. I see that $f(x)=0=f(2)$. What to do?

Comment: What does $[x]$ mean? The integer part of $x$?

Comment: @FrankLu Yes, integer part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} x, &0\leq x<1\\
x-1, &1\leq x<2\\
0, &x=2\end{cases}.$$
Thus $f$ has a jump discontinuity at $x=1$.

On the other hand Darboux theorem tells you that the derivative of a function satisfies the intermediate value property. Now can you see that $f$ fails to satisfy this property?